# ruby class as a parameter in a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this class in a ruby on rails application

```
class ChartData
  def self.user_logs_by_day(logs)
    days_with_hours = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc)}
      logs.each do |log|
        days_with_hours[log.user.name][log.log_date] = log.total_hours
      end
    days_with_hours
  end

  def self.project_logs_by_day(logs)
    days_with_hours = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc)}
      logs.each do |log|
        if !log.project.nil?
          days_with_hours[log.project.name][log.log_date] = log.total_hours
        else
          days_with_hours[@default][log.log_date] = log.total_hours
        end
      end
    days_with_hours
  end
end
```

I want to make the two methods into one like this, because I want to use this method for many models.

```
class ChartData
  def self.logs_by_day(logs, klass)
    days_with_hours = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc)}
      logs.each do |log|
        if !log.klass.nil?
          days_with_hours[log.klass.name][log.log_date] = log.total_hours
        else
          days_with_hours[@default][log.log_date] = log.total_hours
        end
      end
    days_with_hours
  end
end
```

I want to pass the class or model into the method like this

```
ChartData.logs_by_day(logs, Project)
```

How can I handle the parameter Project in the model so it gets to be a instance method on the log?

A rather clumsy attempt

```
1.9.3p125 :026 > Project.name.downcase
 => "project"
```

Any better? Other refactor suggestions are welcome

Comment: `Project.name.downcase` - this way you'll have a string, not an instance method.

Comment: I know that's why it was "A rather clumsy attempt" ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to pass the class? You're not using it anywhere. Pass a symbol.

```
ChartData.logs_by_day(logs, :project)
```

and then

```
def self.logs_by_day(logs, prop)
  # ...
  log.send(prop).name
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks this works. In my next method however I am using the class. Do you know how I can something elegant with the symbol to this `User.chart_lables(firm)`

Comment: Ask another question with that method. Because it's a different situation

Answer (score 0):

For Rails, what you probably want is something like `klass.name.underscore`. This and its counterpart `camelize` are designed to convert between method-style naming conventions and module-style naming conventions. In particular, this will work with class names like "UserData", which should be "user_data" rather than the "userdata" you'd get from just downcasing. You can then pass it as the method selector to `send`.